# Reload UserDetails Object from Database Every Request in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have been looking for a way to reload our Spring Security UserDetails object every request and cannot find an example anywhere.

Does anyone know how to do such a thing?

Basically, we want to reload a user's authorities every request because that user's authorities might change from web request to web request.

For instance, a user that is logged in and is subsequently granted a new authority (and is notified that they have a new authority via email), the only way that I know of that user actually gaining that new authority is by logging out and then logging back in again.  Which I would like to avoid if possible.

Any friendly advice is appreciated.

Comment: What method are you using for your requests? Just Spring MVC or REST, because if you are using REST you could secure your methods to user authorities and use a class that implements HandlerInterceptorAdapter. If you are using REST just google securing REST controllers Spring Framework and you should get some nice examples

Comment: You can find answers in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892733/how-to-immediately-enable-the-authority-after-update-user-authority-in-spring-se

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally, after two years, for the question above and for six years after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/892733/42962), here is an answer on how to reload a user's UserDetails per request with Spring...

To reload a user/security context per request, it is important to override the default behavior of Spring Security's [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.html), which implements the [SecurityContextRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextRepository.html) interface.

The HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository is the class that is used by Spring Security to get the user's security context from the HttpSession.  The code that calls this class is what places the SecurityContext on threadlocal.  So when the `loadContext(HttpRequestResponseHolder requestResponseHolder)` method is called we can turn around and make a request to a [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) or [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) and reload the user/principal.

Some things of concern that have not quite been figured out quite yet.

**Is this code thread safe?**

I have no idea, it depends on if there is a new SecurityContext created per thread/request into the web server.  If there is a new SecurityContext created life is good, but if not, there could be some interesting unexpected behavior like stale object exceptions, the wrong state for a user/principal being saved to the data store, etc...

Our code is 'low risk enough' that we haven't tried to test potential multi-thread issues.

**Is there a performance hit for calling to the database every request?**

Most likely, but we haven't seen noticeable change in our web server response times.

A couple of quick notes on this subject...

- Databases are super smart and they have algorithms to know what and when to cache specific queries.
- We are using hibernate's second level caching.

Benefits we've received from this change:

- It use to be that our UserDetails object that we used to represent the Principal was not Serializable and therefore when we stopped and restarted our tomcat server, all the de-serialized SercurityContexts would have a null principal object and our end users would receive server errors due to null pointer exceptions.  Now that the UserDetails/Principal object is serializable and the user is reloaded per request we can start/restart our server without having to clean out the work directory.
- We have received zero customer complaints about their new permissions not taking affect right away.

**The Code**

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpRequestResponseHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository;
import xxx.repository.security.UserRepository;
import xxx.model.security.User;
import xxx.service.security.impl.acegi.AcegiUserDetails;

public class ReloadUserPerRequestHttpSessionSecurityContextRepository extends HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository {

    // Your particular data store object would be used here...
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public ReloadUserPerRequestHttpSessionSecurityContextRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {

        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public SecurityContext loadContext(HttpRequestResponseHolder requestResponseHolder) {

        // Let the parent class actually get the SecurityContext from the HTTPSession first.
        SecurityContext context = super.loadContext(requestResponseHolder);

        Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();

        // We have two types of logins for our system, username/password
        // and Openid, you will have to specialize this code for your particular application.
        if (authentication instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.createNewUserDetailsFromPrincipal(authentication.getPrincipal());

            // Create a new Authentication object, Authentications are immutable.
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken newAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, authentication.getCredentials(), userDetails.getAuthorities());

            context.setAuthentication(newAuthentication);

        } else if (authentication instanceof OpenIDAuthenticationToken) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.createNewUserDetailsFromPrincipal(authentication.getPrincipal());

            OpenIDAuthenticationToken openidAuthenticationToken = (OpenIDAuthenticationToken) authentication;

            // Create a new Authentication object, Authentications are immutable.
            OpenIDAuthenticationToken newAuthentication = new OpenIDAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getAuthorities(), openidAuthenticationToken.getIdentityUrl(), openidAuthenticationToken.getAttributes());

            context.setAuthentication(newAuthentication);
        }

        return context;
    }

    private UserDetails createNewUserDetailsFromPrincipal(Object principal) {

        // This is the class we use to implement the Spring Security UserDetails interface.
        AcegiUserDetails userDetails = (AcegiUserDetails) principal;

        User user = this.userRepository.getUserFromSecondaryCache(userDetails.getUserIdentifier());

        // NOTE:  We create a new UserDetails by passing in our non-serializable object 'User', but that object in the AcegiUserDetails is transient.
        // We use a UUID (which is serializable) to reload the user.  See the userDetails.getUserIdentifier() method above.
        userDetails = new AcegiUserDetails(user);

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

To plug a new SecurityContextRepository with xml configuration, just set the security-context-repository-ref attribute on the security:http context.

Example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
    <security:http context-repository-ref="securityContextRepository" >
         <!-- intercept-url and other security configuration here... -->
    </security:http>

    <bean id="securityContextRepository" class="xxx.security.impl.spring.ReloadUserPerRequestHttpSessionSecurityContextRepository" >
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="userRepository"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

---

Comment: [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/892733/42962) mentioned got the correct [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6041528/999367). I've added the missed config details in the comment.

Comment: How did you upgrade this to spring-security 6, which is using a bit of a different way to load the context?

Comment: @RüdigerSchulz We have not updated to Spring Security 6 yet.  We are just starting to deal with removing Apache Tiles, which keeps us on Java 11 for now.  It will be quite sometime before we actually have to deal with that particular problem.  I'm a bit surprised that Spring Security 6 doesn't have a way to reload the principal every request.

Comment: In the meantime I found a way to implement the same behaviour with a HandlerInterceptor - which probably works with spring-security 5 as well. Get the context with SecurityContextHolder.getContext().

Answer (score 1):

Hello so wanted to share something related to this issue with Token based authentication, in my case Oauth2.  At first I tried the approach of hooknc above, in my case I was using Token based Authentication, so my Authentication object was instanceOf Oauth2Authentication.  Unlike standard Authentication Principal, Oauth2Authentication object is constructed of the Authorization Request and Authentication object.  Additionally the principal is constructed by using the token itself.  So when trying to reuse the token in another call it would end up with old user data in principal.  So this approach does not work for token based authentication.

My Original problem to be clear was after the user would update user settings, if the user would make other API calls after, it would result in the old user info.  Instead of trying to update the principal I found issuing a new token after update was a better approach.

I also should add that my Authentication Oauth2 scheme is totally stateless, everything is stored in DB.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooo much

Answer (score 1):

**For the side of the admin user changing the other user's authority**: You can try to retrieve the sessions of the affected user and set some attribute to indicate a reload is needed.

If you happen to use Spring Session with session attributes persisted in the database (e.g., to support multiple container instances), you can tag an active session for reload when the admin user makes changes to the authorities:

```
@Autowired
private FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<Session> sessionRepo;

public void tag(String username) {
    Map<String, Session> sessions = sessionRepo.findByIndexNameAndIndexValue
            (FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME, username);
    for (Session s : sessions.values()) {
        s.setAttribute("reloadAuth", true);
        sessionRepo.save(s);
    }
}
```

**For the logged-in user side**: You can write your Spring Security Filter that will check for the session attribute whether to reload the current session's authentication or not. If an admin has tagged it for reload, we retrieve again the `Principal` from the DB and re-set our `Authentication`.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
    if (session != null) {
        Boolean reload = (Boolean) session.getAttribute("reloadAuth");
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(shouldReloadRoles)) {
            session.removeAttribute("reloadAuth");
            /* Do some locking based on session ID if you want just to avoid multiple reloads for a session */
            Authentication newAuth = ... // Load new authentication from DB
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm tring FilterSecurityInterceptor's re-authenticate trick

for form-login with JDBC userDetailsService

1. Authentication's isAuthenticated set to return false.
2. rase-credentials to false. (keep credential in session...
3. when AuthenticationException raised, logout then redirect to login page.

**AuthenticationProvider**

authenticated to false.

```java
package studying.spring;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

public class MyDaoAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

  @Override
  protected Authentication createSuccessAuthentication(Object principal, Authentication authentication, UserDetails user) {

    Authentication result = super.createSuccessAuthentication(principal, authentication, user);
    result.setAuthenticated(false);

    return result;
  }
}
```

**AuthenticationEntryPoint for ExceptionTranslationFilter**

logout and redirect to login page.

```java
package studying.spring;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;

public class MyLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

  public MyLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
    super(loginFormUrl);
  }

  @Override
  protected String determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) {

    if (exception != null) {
      Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    }

    return super.determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(request, response, exception);
  }
}
```

**root-context.xml**

rase-credentials attr. to false.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">

  <security:http entry-point-ref="myLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')"/>
    <security:form-login/>
    <security:logout/>
  </security:http>

  <security:authentication-manager erase-credentials="false">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="myDaoAuthenticationProvider"/>
  </security:authentication-manager>

  <bean id="myLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="studying.spring.MyLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="myDaoAuthenticationProvider" class="studying.spring.MyDaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="jdbcDaoImpl" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jdbcDaoImpl" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="securityDataSource" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="securityDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studying_spring_security" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```