# Spring Oauth2 - reload principals

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have implemented OAuth2 password grant with spring security module. I add own implementation of UserDetails and UserDetailsService (jdbc). I inject User to my controllers with:

```
@AuthenticationPrincipal User user
```

where User is my implementation of UserDetails .
Now I want to add posibility of changing User data without refreshing token.

I try to refresh principals with:

```
User updatedUser = ...
Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(updatedUser, updatedUser.getPassword(), updatedUser.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
```

But it doesn't work, when I invoke another controller method it returns old User object.

Is there any way to change User data without refreshing token? Is any solution to make spring security to always load user data from database (not from Cache)?

Comment: In which layer of the application do you refresh principals?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to achieve this from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072235/reload-userdetails-object-from-database-every-request-in-spring-security#34956579). I created `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`

```
@Bean
public ReloadUserPerRequestHttpSessionSecurityContextRepository userDetailContextRepository() {
    return new ReloadUserPerRequestHttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
}
```

and add this to my `HttpSecurity` from the class of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as

```
    .and()
        .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
    .and()
        .securityContext()
            .securityContextRepository(userDetailContextRepository())
```

Below is sample codes to fetch updated user informations at every requests. You can fetch from your API server or `user-info-url` of your oauth2 configuration.

```
public class ReloadUserPerRequestHttpSessionSecurityContextRepository extends HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository {

    @Override
    public SecurityContext loadContext(HttpRequestResponseHolder requestResponseHolder) {
        SecurityContext context = super.loadContext(requestResponseHolder);

        Authentication auth = context.getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null && auth instanceof OAuth2Authentication) {
            OAuth2Authentication oldAuth = (OAuth2Authentication) auth;
            if (oldAuth.getPrincipal() instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
                createNewUserDetailsFromPrincipal(oldAuth.getPrincipal());
            }
            context.setAuthentication(oldAuth);
        }
        return context;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void createNewUserDetailsFromPrincipal(Object principal) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> userDetailInfo = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) principal;
        // fetch User informations from your API server or your database or
        // 'user-info-url' of oauth2 endpoint
        userDetailInfo.put("name", "EDITED_USER_NAME");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but this is just a guess, I think you you also need to clear `SecurityContext`.

First clear security context with `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();` then your code to set authentication

```
Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(updatedUser, updatedUser.getPassword(), updatedUser.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
```

Comment: Applications these secured by Oauth2 can't assign with `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` type authentication.